# Allow Facebook posts to be liked by the public

Tags: facebook

How do I change my settings to allow non-friends to 'like' my posts? They can 'share' but not comment or like. My setting is public on my wall.

Answer (score 7):

Your non-friends are similar to [Followers](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=followers) (click link to change settings);  in the sense that the same setting applies to people who can be termed *Everybody*.

[image: Facebook - Follower Settings]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is it a bug?